# ggplot: update geom defaults for multiple discrete colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

For `ggplot2`, I would like to be able to set defaults for when a color or fill aesthetic is mapped to (discrete) data.  While I'm aware that I can use `scale_*_manual()` at each plot call, I want to set a default.

It is possible to update the default color for a geom using:

```
update_geom_defaults(geom = "bar", new = list(fill = "red")
```

However this is overridden when an aesthetic is mapped. Providing a vector for fill does not work.

In addition, I have a set of 10 predetermined colors that I want to use, in order, rather than the more common solution of using a pallette (ie `viridis`, which still requires a scall_*_viridis call at each plot).

Is there a method for doing this?

Example:

Currently you can supply extra colors to `scale_*_manual()` without any problem, it just uses as many as it needs.  How can I get the same result by setting the default colors used any time a fill/color aes is specified instead of the default ggplot ones?

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
col_colors <- c("#741D5A", "#DD9E27", "#33439B", "#ED1C24", 
                "#24420E", "#BB4126", "#AE9B32", "#783545")

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = wt, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
     geom_col() + 
     scale_fill_manual(values = col_colors)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: https://www.shanelynn.ie/themes-and-colours-for-r-ggplots-with-ggthemr/

Comment: I followed this blog to do the same thing: [https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/creating-corporate-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/creating-corporate-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2) *I don't have the rep to leave this in the comments.*